# Pandas Dataframe-space separator

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read some text file (coordination file) using pandas. The contents are [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPMTz.jpg)separated by space, and I used 'delim_whitespace=True', 'sep='\s+', but it doesn't work. I could just see some error message (parsererror: Expected 1 fields in line 5....).

My code for reading csv is as belows.

```
 df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='\s+', header=None, engine='python')
```

I used delimiter, sep='  ', sep = '\s+', delim_whitespace=True.

Data reading of some coordination file

```
 df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='\s+', header=None, engine='python')
```

parsererror: Expected 1 fields in line 5....

My file is as belows and I think the sixth line (coordination starting point) makes the problem. If I erase the initial five line, the separtor works.

If I use delimiter = '  ', then it works, but the separator does not work as shown belows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7MrZ.jpg)

Comment: You may want to add `skiprows=5` in your `read_csv`.

Comment: Thnx a lot for your comment! It works! But I have two more questions. The first five lines making the problem repeats in the middle of the file. So if I don't cut that part before reading CSV type file, it causes the same problem again. In that case, how can I fix the problem? How can I skip the rows placed in the middle of the file? Another question is that if I want to use the data of the first five lines, would it be better making another dataframe for that?